# How to plot $z= 5-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, 0 \le z \le 5$ in mathematica?

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, math-software, mathematica

> Could anybody tell me how to plot $z= 5-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, 0 \le z \le 5$ in mathematica?

I haven't done much on multivariable yet, but I am inquisitive to know how to plot this cone on mathematica?

Comment: i would use cylindrical coords $z=5-r, 0\leq r\leq5, 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ after looking up how to plot something like this in the mathematica "help"

Comment: You might be interested in the proposal for a [Mathematica-specific StackExchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica). We are quite close to getting into beta, so please consider committing soon!

Comment: @Verbeia:I have committed, hope we go to beta phase soon :-)

Comment: @MaX you don't seem to be in the list. You might not have confirmed your email address. Please do this. The confirmation email might be caught in your spam-catcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot3D[5-Sqrt[x^2+y^2],{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},PlotRange->{0,5}]
```

Answer (score 5):

`RegionPlot3D` can be useful for this.

```
RegionPlot3D[
 z - (5 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]),
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

To restrict the plot to $0 \le z \le 5$, you can use the option `RegionFunction`, like so:

```
Plot3D[5 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < z < 5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An essential difference between `RegionFunction` and `PlotRange`:

- when using `RegionFunction`, all points generated outside the region are discarded before building the 3D object to show, and the boundary of the region is computed and plotted nicely.
- when using `PlotRange`, all points are included in the 3D object, but it is clipped to a box determined by the plot range while rendering.

You can only restrict what's being show to a box using `PlotRange` while `RegionFunction` lets you specify a region of any shape.  Please also see [my two answers here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Bjy1Z5Ogwpk/NdMiaY0iQ9wJ).

---

You may also want to use a custom mesh, to make it prettier.  Here's how to do it without leaving Cartesian coordinates:

```
Plot3D[5 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < z < 5], 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, z]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, z], 
                  Function[{x, y, z}, ArcTan[x, y]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Looks pretty. +1

Comment: @Mr.W I tried to make them pretty and anti-aliased but I ran into [the problem of ticks not scaling properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805451/tick-marks-dont-scale-in-graphics-why-and-how-to-fix-this).